# Using tabs to navigate to different html files (HTML, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my first time doing something like this.

Let's say in my HTML file I have something like

```
<div class="main_tabs">
    <ul class="tabs">
       <li id="home_tab"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li id="other_tab"><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Then in my JavaScript file I have something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.main_tabs .tabs a').on('click', function(e)  {
       e.preventDefault();
       switch(this.id){
           case "home_tab":
           window.location.href = "index.html";
           break;
           case "other_tab":
           window.location.href = "other.html";
           break;
       }
   });
});
```

When I click the tabs, nothing happens. I tried a bunch of different stuff, but I couldn't get it to work. Could anyone help me (by the way, I need to keep the preventDefault to do some other stuff in the function, so I need to manually do the page changing)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `id` or parent `li` since `a` tag doesn't have the `id` attribute.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.main_tabs .tabs a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (this.parentNode.id) {
    // -----^-- get parent node and it's id
      case "home_tab":
        window.location.href = "index.html";
        break;
      case "other_tab":
        window.location.href = "other.html";
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_tabs">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li id="home_tab"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="other_tab"><a href="other.html">Other</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I edited that back in. That was what it originally was, so thanks for confirming that. However, I must have other problems because it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, my tabs link properly now.

Comment: @Yifan : glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the jquery since you are already using anchor in html.
Please see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp.